# parse objeect nested array objects

Tags: arrays, object, parsing

Detail post  [Nestjs Dto as a array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72615616/19331897)

how i can parse this data

```
[1,"After every minute","Will turn on device after every minute","\"[object Object]\"","\"[object Object]\"",1,"After every minute","Will turn on device after every minute","\"[object Object]\"","\"[object Object]\"",1,"After every minute","Will turn on device after every minute","\"[object Object]\"","\"[object Object]\"",1,"After every minute","Will turn on device after every minute","\"[object Object]\"","\"[object Object]\"",1,"After every minute","Will turn on device after every minute","\"[object Object]\"","\"[object Object]\"",1,"After every minute","Will turn on device after every minute","\"[object Object]\"","\"[object Object]\"",1,"After every minute","Will turn on device after every minute","\"[object Object]\"","\"[object Object]\"",1,"After every minute","Will turn on device after every minute","\"[object Object]\"","\"[object Object]\""]
```

value shown [object Object]\ here
when i stringfiy with `JSON.strigifiy`  it shows "[object Object]"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72615616/19331897